# WSL2 not installing

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I got a new laptop with windows 20h2 build 19042.1766.

I tried installing wsl2 with

```
wsl --install
```

on windows powershell on admin mode. It gives the following output.

```
Installing: Virtual Machine Platform
Virtual Machine Platform has been installed.
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.
Downloading: WSL Kernel
Installing: WSL Kernel
WSL Kernel has been installed.
The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted.
```

There must be Ubuntu download happening here as per the installation steps. But thats missing. Also nothing happens after I reboot.

wsl does nothing on the powershell. Not even says its an unknown command.

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> wsl
PS C:\Users\xxx> wsl --list --online
PS C:\Users\xxx> wsl --help
PS C:\Users\xxx> wsl --install -d Ubuntu
PS C:\Users\xxx>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You must select and install WSL distributions yourself.

Comment: @DanielB 'wsl --install -d Ubuntu' doesn't work as well

Comment: What does the command do exactly and why are you running an unsupported version of Windows 10?

Comment: unsupported version of windows? didn't get you

Comment: Windows 10 20H2 is unsupported. You should upgrade to Windows 10 21H2. If you run these commands within a command prompt do they output anything? Can you provide a screenshot showing that Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Subsystem for Linux are both installed?

Comment: @AnilPBabu Hmm.  Something doesn't add up there (I think).  Can you double-check your Windows release?  The `wsl --install` option didn't get added to *Insider* builds until [late 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/distro-installation-added-to-wsl-install-in-windows-10-insiders-preview-build-20246/) and wasn't released until (iirc) 21H1 or even 21H2.   If you are using 20H2, then `wsl --install` should just error out, but it's doing *something*, so that's weird.

Comment: @DanielB I think you are mistaken on that.  `wsl --install` by itself will default to the "Ubuntu" (unversioned, 20.04) distribution being installed -- After the base features (WSL, VMP, and kernel) of course.  From [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#install-wsl-command), *"This command will enable the required optional components, download the latest Linux kernel, set WSL 2 as your default, and install a Linux distribution for you (Ubuntu by default, see below to change this)."*  Of course, that's when it's working, which it apparently isn't for the OP.

Comment: @AnilPBabu What happens if you follow the [Manual Installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) steps?  Try *just* enabling WSL1 to start with (Step1).  After rebooting, does `wsl -l -v` show anything different?  Also, I mentioned in a comment on your Stack Overflow question that sometimes you'll see a message when rebooting that, *"We couldn’t complete the updates. Undoing changes"*  Are you experiencing that?  Thanks.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Also after step1 of manual installation (WSL 1), wsl -l -v doesnt do a thing. It acts dead. I didnt notice anything on reboot. Have tried multiple times rebooting now.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I tried Manual installation of WSL. All steps seems to work, except the last one of installing linux distro. I did it manually (not from store). downloaded the package Ubuntu.appx. But the command "Add-AppxPackage .\Ubuntu.appx" is dead now. Does nothing. Think there is some connection between WSL and this command as both dont work.

Comment: I even tried installing older version of Ubuntu 1604. No hope

Comment: @AnilPBabu Right.  If even `wsl -l -v` isn't working, then it's almost certainly not going to be able to register the distribution during the package installation .  What is `Get-Service LxssManager` (PowerShell) showing?  Is there any chance that you have Sophos Safeguard?  That was the issue for someone in a [related Github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5836#issuecomment-1142716421).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I Managed to install "wsl-debian-gnulinux". But while I load the Debian it continuously asks for username, no matter whatever I give it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds LxssManager status is running

Comment: @AnilPBabu Hmm.  Was the Debian from the Store?  Also, doubt this is going to tell us much, but can you confirm `Get-Command wsl` (PowerShell)?

Comment: Also, is the account a personal one?  Corporate or University?  Just want to know if we should consider factors that might be outside your control (permissions, etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137307/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-anil-p-babu).